# What does bind do in this react example?

Tags: reactjs

What does **bind** do in this statement **this.tick.bind(this)** in the following code:

```
export class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {count: props.initialCount};
  }
  tick() {
    this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.tick.bind(this)}>
        Clicks: {this.state.count}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The code is taken from the [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html) site.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`.bind()` sets the `this` of the function it is used to create, to be whatever parameter is passed in. [Docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

In this case, it sets the `this` of the `tick()` function to be the `render()` function's context.

You would do this because when a function is used as a DOM event handler, the `this` is set to be the element that dispatched the DOM event. You want to guarantee that the `this` is the one you expect, since it's used in `tick()`

Answer (score 0):

It's used to pass arguments to the tick() method, it's just Javascript and nothing that is react specific.