# What does this.function = this.function.bind(this) do in the following context? ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am following a tutorial series on udemy and the instructor hasn't really explained the following line of code:

```
this.getrandomnum = this.getrandomnum.bind(this);
```

So I am a bit confused as to what it does and was hoping to get some help. My code works with or without the above line.

Here is the full code:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <h1> Hello</h1>
      <Body />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Body extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.getRandomNumber = this.getRandomNumber.bind(this);
  }
  getRandomNumber(){
    console.log('some random number')
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <button onClick={this.getRandomNumber}>Random Number</button>
      )
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does bind do in this react example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32124213/what-does-bind-do-in-this-react-example)

Answer (score 1):

It binds `this` to the function in the class when it's called. It's importance is to retain the context of `this` when it's called. Typically this is done on callbacks such as the `onClick` handler in the `Body` component.

Your code still works because you're not referencing any type of context (other than the `window.console` function, which is the `this` in this case). If you didn't bind `this` in the constructor and had this:

```
<button onClick={this.getRandomNumber}>Random Number</button>
```

and in the `getRandomNumber`:

```
getRandomNumber(e){
    console.log(e)
}
```

it would return an error that `e` is `undefined` because the context of this function is bound to the `window` object. In this case `e` does not exist.

Read more about: [handling events in the React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html) and [`bind`](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/understanding-javascript-function-prototype-bind/)

Comment: So in that situation (getRandomNumber(e){console.log(e)} if I had just done <button onClick={()=> this.getRandomNumber(e)} would this then work?

Comment: `<button onClick={(e)=> this.getRandomNumber(e)}` to be exact. When the button is clicked `getRandomNumber` will know the target element it's referencing.